# the wired network connection is active ,but can't connect to the internet

Tags: networking, dns

The operating system is Ubuntu10.04. The icon of `network connection` on the panel shows
the wired network connection is active, but I can't access to the Internet. So I set the network configuration manually.I changed the `/etc/resolv.conf` as below:

`nameserver   202.112.14.151`

202.112.14.151 is my school's DNS server's IP. 192.168.2.1 is router' address. I also changed the `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.2.107
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.1
```

And `/var/run/network/ifstate`:

```
 lo=lo
 eth0=eth0
```

My classmates (we'are in the same room and use the same router) used

```
address:192.168.2.254
netmask:255.255.255.0
gateway:192.168.2.1   
DNS server:202.112.14.151
```

to configure the network  on `Windows xp` can access to the Internet.
I typed the command `ping 192.168.2.1` but it reminds me the host 192.168.2.1 is unreachable. Do I neglect something? Please tell me, Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 192.168.2.1 is unreachable, there is something wrong with your local area network. This could mean your adapter / cable, but you say the panel shows an active connection. Are you connected to the right switch / right port on the switch? Are you using the right kind of cable (try changing)?

Try `ping 192.168.2.255` to see if you can reach any nodes on the network.

Comment: I changed the connected switch port on the switch and used another cable. Then I could access to the Internet. So I wondered that maybe the cable I used before was bad. But I used the original cable connected to the new port and found that the Internet was accessible. So the cable is intact. I used the original cable to connect to the original port and the Internet was still accessible. I really wondered what's the problem. Now I solved the problem by changing port and cable. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I have no other choice so I only have to accept your answer.Thanks for your tips

Answer (score -1):

Here The Solution
`   public static void main(String[] args) {
        String IP;

```
    try {
        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        IP=ip.getHostAddress();
        //Host NET ID
        System.out.println("Current IP address : " + IP);

        NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);

        byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();
        //Type
        System.out.println("Type Eth0/wlan     :"+network.getName());
        //SubNet Prefix
        System.out.println("SubNet ID :"+network.getInterfaceAddresses().get(0).getNetworkPrefixLength());
        System.out.println();
        //HostName
        System.out.println("HostName  :"+ip.getHostName());
        //MAC
        System.out.print("Current MAC address : ");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));        
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());

        InetAddress i = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        byte[] ip1 = i.getAddress(); 
        for (int b = 0; b <255;b++) { 
            ip1[3] = (byte)b;
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip1); 
            if (address.isReachable(3000)) {
                System.out.println("\tIP :"+address.getHostAddress());
                NetworkInterface network1 = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(address);
                System.out.println("Type Eth0/wlan     :"+network.getName());
                System.out.println();
            } else if (!address.getHostAddress().equals(address.getHostName())) { 
                System.out.println("\tIP :"+address.getHostAddress());
            } else {
                System.out.println("NO");
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}`
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rhjn2.png)

Comment: This looks to have very little to do with the question